# How to log Linux commands ran from a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc, command-history

I am able to log commands executed on bash shell using `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a > .....` , but this wont log commands executed from within a shell script.
Is there any way to log command ran from shell script as well as the shell command history?

Comment: Technically a script is a log of commands that are executed when running the script.

Comment: @Gantendo Okay, but I am logging these commands for auditing, and user can bypass this logging by running the command through a script file and delete the file. So how do I log actual command executed through the script?

Comment: "For auditing" – so [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before. Is reinventing the wheel a wise move? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670957/how-to-log-every-single-command-executed-from-shell-script & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206159/how-to-track-log-commands-executed-on-a-shell Or google: "linux log commands executed by script" and "Linux audit software" (without quotes)

Comment: Hmmm, "user can bypass this logging" :::: Well, user can also change the PROMPT COMMAND to bypass ; user can also start a new shell csh or tcsh ; user can delete the history file ; user can also start the command with a space to avoid logging :::: Basically the Solution is wrong and you should look into auditing tools, not history logging !